# Trouble with Gitlab CI and VITE environment variables

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, vite

I have searched (both offical documentation and what feels like all of the internet) and tested multiple approaches, but I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around environment variables in VITE with Gitlab pipelines.

With CRA this worked great (using `CREATE_APP_var1`).

I now have the following setup in my pipeline, and deployments to dev and production got their different set of variable-values (shortened for brevity):

```
stages:
  - build
  - image
  - chart
  - deploy
.build:
  stage: build
  image: node:16
  variables:
    CI: 'false'
    VITE_ENV: '$ENVIRONMENT'
    VITE_COMMIT: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE'
  before_script:
    - printenv | grep -E '^(VITE_|ENVIRONMENT)' # this is to print what gitlab sees, and it sees the correct values from `build:dev:`-step
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
    expire_in: 2 weeks

build:dev:
  extends:
    - .build
  environment:
    name: Dev
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: 'development'
    IMAGE_NAME: 'image/path'
    VITE_var1: 'value1'
    VITE_TESTMESSAGE: 'This is a test message'
  only:
    - develop-branch

build:prod:
  extends:
    - .build
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
    VITE_BUILD: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    VITE_var1: 'value1'
    VITE_var2: 'value2'
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

So my pipeline triggers on any pushed commit to develop-branch, and for production only commits with a tag. So far so good.

In my repository I also have the files:

- .env.development.local - this is loaded fine and localhost holds development values
- .env.production - this works in production, all values are loaded

Now, seeing as I am passing to the build stage, via extension build:dev the values for `VITE_var1` and `VITE_TESTMESSAGE` I assume that these will "win" over any other variables with the same name. I am accessing the values in my code like this, just to verify if it works:

```
config.js
console.log('VITE_var1 env', import.meta.env.VITE_var1); // returns prod value
console.log('VITE_TESTMESSAGE env', import.meta.env.VITE_TESTMESSAGE); // returns undefined
```

No matter what I do here I get the values from .env.production (when running the dev-steps) and variables set in the ci-file is ignored.

I have also tried setting up .env.development and running a separate build-dev script in package.json:

```
"build-dev": "tsc && vite build --mode development",
```

and if ci commit branch == develop-branch:

```
- if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "Dev" ]]; then npm run build-dev; else npm run build; fi
```

Any pointers as to what I am clearly not understanding here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of trial and error, we figured out the issue. Posting our solution here in case anyone else is in a similar rabbit-hole.

This is mainly an issue born of ignorance. We were barking up the wrong tree when we were trying to fix everything with the `build`-step.

We have the `image` with `image:dev` and `image:prod` variantes step where the issue actually lies. So, to fix it we change the image step to point to two different `dockerfile` instances (with kaniko), and in each we run the `tsc && vite build` (prod) and `tsc && vite build --mode development` (dev) respectively.

This makes the different image steps respect either `.env.production` and `.env.development` in the repository based on where the code is deployed to (branches).